# Neighborhood Complex Connectedness Algorithm

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, algorithms, simplicial-complex

Is there an algorithm that can decide, wether the polyhedron of a neighborhood complex (as defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NeighborhoodComplex.html)) of a given finite graph is simply connected? There is no such algorithm for arbitrary simplicial complexes, see [k-connectedness of simplicial complexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183865/k-connectedness-of-simplicial-complexes/2183877#2183877).